# Blazor - 'msxsl:script' element is not supported on this framework because it does not support run-time code generation

Tags: c#, .net, progressive-web-apps, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a problem with using XslCompiledTransform in Blazor Webassembly.

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: 'msxsl:script' element is not
> supported on this framework because it does not support run-time code
> generation

[image: Error in google chrome console]

```
public async Task<string> TransformSomething(string xml, string kluczPakietu, string kodPakietu)
        {
            var xslFile = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("transform.xsl");

            //change bytearray to string - valid is working here.
            string transformataHTML = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(xslFile);

            
            XDocument oldDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var newDocument = new XDocument();


            
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(transformataHTML))
            {
                using (XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
                {
                    XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
                    argsList.AddParam("SVG", "", "enabled");
                    argsList.AddParam("klucz", "", kluczPakietu);
                    argsList.AddParam("kod", "", kodPakietu);
                    XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings();
                    xsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;
                    xsltSettings.EnableScript = true;

                    var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();


                    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    xslt.Load(xsltReader);

                    //here is exception
                    transformer.Load(xsltReader, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
                    //transformer.Load(xsltReader);
                    using (XmlReader oldDocumentReader = oldDocument.CreateReader())
                    {
                        using (XmlWriter newDocumentWriter = newDocument.CreateWriter())
                        {
                            transformer.Transform(oldDocumentReader, argsList, newDocumentWriter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return newDocument.ToString();
        }
```

Is it possible to do it in Blazor Webassembly? In Blazor Server-side the script works.

Comment: The error is quite clear: Blazor/Wasm does not support this. Make sure you test this with the latest .net 5 edition. After that, check the roadmap(s) on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XslCompiledTransform` would try to generate new .NET code at run-time and would expect a JIT to compile it to native code for the underlying machine. Since WebAssembly does not support this (just like other platforms that require AOT like iOS), you cannot use it.

Use the `XslTransform` class instead of `XslCompiledTransform` to work with XSLT on these platforms.

Update: Also note that scripts inside XSLT always need run-time code generation, so even if `XslCompiledTransform` would fall back to non-compiled transform, scripts are only implemented for run-time code generation at the moment:

> The XslCompiledTransform class supports embedded scripts using the
> msxsl:script element. When the style sheet is loaded, any defined
> functions are compiled to Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) by
> the Code Document Object Model (CodeDOM) and are executed during run
> time. The assembly generated from the embedded script block is
> separate than the assembly generated for the style sheet.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script)

Comment: Good explanation :) When I change XslCompiledTransform to XslTransform, I get an exception about XSLT scripts.I need to have "EnableDocumentFunction = true" and "EnableScript = true" because of that I use XslCompiledTransform. The XSLT file is from the client company, I do not want to change it - it has like 5k lines of code. Do you have some tricks to deal with it? Right now I created Azure function for this :P However, I prefer Full-Blazor Web assembly solution.

Comment: Then I guess you are out of luck at the moment . you could file an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime for supporting scripts in an AOT-friendly way to raise awareness of that feature limitation.

Comment: I largely agree except for "a JIT to compile it". the XSLT stuff shouldn't care about native code or interpreted IL. Supporting this on WebAssembly does seem possible. It just isn't implemented (yet).